# One finger restriction on UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, multi-touch

As you know an UIView can detect multi fingers. I just would like to restrict this functionality to one finger.
How  can I do that ? I didn't find a method ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following will disable multi-touch in the specified view.

`view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;`